# Are "small" and "little" interchangeable here

Tags: word-usage

There will be little/small rains about noon.

Are "little" and "small" interchangeable here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We don't use size-adjectives - like big, large, little or small - when describing rain. We describe its density, using *light* or *heavy*.

Note too that *rain* in this context is singular.

Examples:

> *There will be light rain at about noon.*
>
> *There will be a shower (or showers) around noon.*

Comment: So the wrong collocations of "little rain", "small rain" are widespread: Google  4,680,000 hits for "little rain"; 641,000 hits for "small rain".

Comment: @NewPlanet "There has been little rain" does not describe the size of the raindrops. "Small rain clouds" don't contain small rain and neither do small rain showers , small rain shadows, small rain frogs, small rain trees, small rain hats or small rain bags.

Comment: Rain is often plural. e.g. “The summer rains meant a good crop this year.”

Comment: @jwpfox Thank you. I've changed it.

Comment: What about "thunder"? Only "heavy thunder" is acceptable? Doesn't "small/big thunder" work?

Comment: Small and big don't work for thunder. But it is a sound. Lots of words describe sounds: loud, quiet, booming, deafening, ear-splitting... It can rumble, crash, roar, explode, echo, rattle things...